# Excel2latex produces broken vertical lines

Tags: tables, excel, excel2latex

So I used [Excel2latex](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/support/excel2latex?lang=en) to convert the following table into latex code:

[image]

The code produced (along with the environment to make a MWE) is:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,hmargin={2.54cm,2.54cm},vmargin={3.17cm,3.17cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
% Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'Sheet2'
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Add caption}
    \begin{tabular}{|r|r|r|}
    \toprule
    Date  & open  & high \\
    \midrule
    2016-07-11 & 650.3800 & 651.9800 \\
    \midrule
    2016-07-12 & 651.2500 & 675.5000 \\
    \midrule
    2016-07-13 & 666.2500 & 671.4500 \\
    \midrule
    2016-07-14 & 655.3000 & 663.9900 \\
    \midrule
    2016-07-15 & 661.4000 & 669.9800 \\
    \midrule
    2016-07-18 & 680.0000 & 684.9400 \\
    \midrule
    2016-07-19 & 675.5100 & 676.8700 \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%

\end{document}
```

The output is:

[image]

with the vertical lines discontinued at every intersection with horizontal lines.

What I want is a table with unbroken, continuous vertical lines. What should I do? Thanks!

Comment: if you read the booktabs documentation the author makes it _very_ clear that he considers vertical lines to be evil and that breaking them in booktabs is by design. Do not load booktabs and use standard latex `\hline` not `\midrule` if you want continuous lines

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks. That was what I thought initially, but it seems that the `\midrule`s were produced by Excel2latex by default and this is unconfigurable..

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Nevermind, the `bookstabs` package actually can be turned off. Just found out.

Comment: I do prefer the tables produced by booktabs.  The question would be why excel2latex produces booktab commands but not a booktab recommended table.

Comment: @Teepeemm there is actually a booktabs package checkbox on the Excel2latex panel. When unchecked, it produces the traditional `\hline` fashioned vertical lines.

Comment: @vim Thanks un-checking booktabs package did the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`booktabs` discourages many horizontal lines, and strongly discourages vertical lines, to such an extant that it doesn't guarantee that vertical lines will work properly.  The approach recommended by `booktabs` would be

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
% Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'Sheet2'
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Add caption}
    \begin{tabular}{rrr}
    \toprule
    Date  & open  & high \\
    \midrule
    2016-07-11 & 650.3800 & 651.9800 \\
    2016-07-12 & 651.2500 & 675.5000 \\
    2016-07-13 & 666.2500 & 671.4500 \\
    2016-07-14 & 655.3000 & 663.9900 \\
    2016-07-15 & 661.4000 & 669.9800 \\
    2016-07-18 & 680.0000 & 684.9400 \\
    2016-07-19 & 675.5100 & 676.8700 \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%

\end{document}
```

[image: table output]

Answer (score 3):

If you really want to add vertical rules (even if it is not in the spirit of `booktabs`) you can use `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` which has a key `vlines` which will add all the vertical rules.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Add caption}
    \begin{NiceTabular}{rrr}[vlines]
    \toprule
    Date  & open  & high \\
    \midrule
    2016-07-11 & 650.3800 & 651.9800 \\
    2016-07-12 & 651.2500 & 675.5000 \\
    2016-07-13 & 666.2500 & 671.4500 \\
    2016-07-14 & 655.3000 & 663.9900 \\
    2016-07-15 & 661.4000 & 669.9800 \\
    2016-07-18 & 680.0000 & 684.9400 \\
    2016-07-19 & 675.5100 & 676.8700 \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{NiceTabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%

\end{document}
```

Prior to version 5.0 of `nicematrix`, you had to put `{RRR}` instead of `{rrr}`.

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 2):

I will answer your question exactly, because it might be useful for other users of the very good `excel2latex add-in`   to export an excel table to LaTeX with minimal effort. https://ctan.org/pkg/excel2latex?lang=en

`So I used Excel2latex to convert the following table into latex code, ...`

`What I want is a table with continuous and unbroken vertical lines. That I have to do?`

The culprit part in this case is  `booktabs`, which insert a space between the rows to separate the contents of the cells from the horizontal lines.
I ran into the same problem with vertical lines and also with colored rows or cells.

When using the excel2latex plugin, uncheck the option `Booktabs package`. The generated code will now insert `\bigstrut` to achieve separation, so you will have to include `\usepackage{bigstrut}` in your preamble.

It will use `\hline` to draw the horizontal lines.

[image]

I started from your original code and just copied and pasted the result from excel2latex. The output exactly matches your requirements, including vertical and horizontal lines. I just added a caption for clarity.

What else can we require from a tool?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,hmargin={2.54cm,2.54cm},vmargin={3.17cm,3.17cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{bigstrut} % added to replace booktabs

\begin{document}
% Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'Sheet2'
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{With the booktabs option}
    \begin{tabular}{|r|r|r|}
    \toprule
    Date  & open  & high \\
    \midrule
    2016-07-11 & 650.3800 & 651.9800 \\
    \midrule
    2016-07-12 & 651.2500 & 675.5000 \\
    \midrule
    2016-07-13 & 666.2500 & 671.4500 \\
    \midrule
    2016-07-14 & 655.3000 & 663.9900 \\
    \midrule
    2016-07-15 & 661.4000 & 669.9800 \\
    \midrule
    2016-07-18 & 680.0000 & 684.9400 \\
    \midrule
    2016-07-19 & 675.5100 & 676.8700 \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%


% Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'Sheet1'
\begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    \caption{Without the booktabs option}
    \begin{tabular}{|r|r|r|}
        \hline
        Date  &  open &  high \bigstrut\\
        \hline
        2016-07-11 & 650.3800 & 651.9800 \bigstrut\\
        \hline
        2016-07-12 & 651.2500 & 675.5000 \bigstrut\\
        \hline
        2016-07-13 & 666.2500 & 671.4500 \bigstrut\\
        \hline
        2016-07-14 & 655.3000 & 663.9900 \bigstrut\\
        \hline
        2016-07-15 & 661.4000 & 669.9800 \bigstrut\\
        \hline
        2016-07-18 & 680.0000 & 684.9400 \bigstrut\\
        \hline
        2016-07-19 & 675.5100 & 676.8700 \bigstrut\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}%
    \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%


\end{document}
```

[image]